# Can we move Amazon Honeycode Apps to Android Play store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-honeycode

Am Exploring Amazon Honeycode Beta version for web/Mobile app development. Am able to develop an app in Amazon Honeycode Portal. Am trying to understand that is there any possibility to move the honeycode app to Android Play store or Amazon restrict only to Team members who has installed Honeycode app  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can invite users to the [app](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-honeycode-build-web-mobile-apps-without-writing-code/) however are you asking for an Android Native app?
It depends how easy it is to jump out of the [walled garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_platform). If your app is a fully fledged website then you're good to go directly to the app and use a thin wrapper like [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/). However based on the documentation you're app is making api calls, the HoneyCode app is doing the heavy lifting for the frontend.
To build your own you would need a frontend to make the same api calls and render it.
The api only has two [api](https://honeycodecommunity.aws/t/honeycode-apis/127)s. Probably check if you can get the data you want working first before building the frontend.
Something like [amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/) handles the frontend better.